# Unknown custom element with Storybook and Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, storybook

I try to use Vuetify with Storybook.

First, i create the project

```
vue create identity-card
```

Add Storybook

```
npx -p @storybook/cli sb init
```

Install Vuetify

```
vue add vuetify
```

Add vue-cli-plugin-vuetify-storybook

```
vue add vuetify-storybook
```

Install js-beautify

```
npm install js-beautify
```

And run

```
npm run storybook
```

I create a folder "Login" in components

Create the "LoginForm.vue", from https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/centered/

And add "LoginForm.stories.js"

```
import MyLoginForm from './LoginForm.vue';

export default {
    title: 'LoginForm',
    component: MyLoginForm,
}

export const Template = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
    props: Object.keys(argTypes),
    components: { MyLoginForm },
    template: `<my-login-form />`
});
```

But i have a lots of error like "Unknown custom element: ". What did I do wrong ?

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: I think you should use this `<MyLoginForm />` instead of `<my-login-form />`